# Does java have an equivalent to the C# `using` statement

Tags: java

I know there are other questions *like* this, but they do not answer my question.

in C#, you would use:

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Helllo, World);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

You use `using System;` from having to do this:

```
namespace Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Helllo, World);
    System.Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

In Java, is there an equivalent to C#'s `using System;`?

Comment: `import static`

Comment: Java supports a `*` suffix on `import` statements, but the Java community mostly considers them poor style (with some exceptions). This is in contrast to the C# community which liberally uses `using` statements that import an entire namespace.

Comment: And here I thought this question was going to be about using blocks and disposables.

Comment: Why does the C# community encourage it when the Java community discourages it?

Comment: Java folks like to see each individual class that you use/import at the top of the source listing.  It makes for lots of boilerplate reading but each package name and class is fully spelled out and there's no guessing which class name comes from which package.  With `*` you're never really sure where each class comes from.  So the former is preferred.  Some of this preference is just what the people who are considered leaders in the community prefer.

Comment: It's something that is generally done by the IDE and folded up so you don't see it. However, when something goes wrong and you wonder why this class is not having this method or behaving as it should, it's reeeeeally easier to find your problem when the imports are explicitly declared individually than searching through a whole namespace to find it was the wrong class two rabbit holes down that direction

Comment: Those are all great points, but then why do C# users use `using` statements?

Comment: Rehi. Unrelated ... I saw your question on class file content. The thing you forgot about: the java compiler has to turn "abstract" source code into specific byte code. Your code examples contained a lot of boxing/unboxing (int to Integer and back) ... in source code, you dont see that, but the compiler has to create byte code instructions! in other words: study the java bytecode spec, and use javap to *dis-assemble* class files into byte code instructions to understand how many things are going on there!

Comment: This is not the place to ask, but... Where would I go to ask a question not meant to be on Stack Overflow? P.S. @GhostCat thanks for the answer both of my questions :)

Comment: Quora.com is more open towards topics, and often you get good technical answers there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are addressing why the communities of these languages have settled on different approaches, but to answer the question directly:

In Java, the `import` statement allows for a `*` suffix to indicate that all classes from a namespace should be imported and usable within the current file without any prefix:

```java
import java.util.*;
```

This is basically equivalent to something like

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

However, the Java standard library and the C# standard library are organized quite differently, so there is no declaration that is exactly the same as C#'s `using System`.

In Java, however, the `java.lang` package is always implicitly imported, and `java.lang` contains many things that would be in C#'s `System`, so you could say that Java makes `using System` *implicit*!

For example, in C#, you need `using System;` to be able to write `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");`, but in Java, you don't need `import java.lang.System;` to be able to write `System.out.println("Hello, world!");`.

Java also has a feature called `import static`, where you can import *members* of a class rather than just the class itself or the classes in a package. So you could do something like `import static java.lang.System.out;` or `import static java.lang.System.*;` and then write `out.println("Hello, world!");` if you prefer.

C# also has a feature called a namespace alias where you can import a single name from another namespace, optionally renaming it as you go. So you could write `using C = System.Console;` and then write `C.WriteLine("Hello, world!");` if you prefer.

Both of these latter options are not commonly used with the standard library, but might be used in special cases, or with special classes that are designed to be used in such a way.

Comment: Maybe static imports also deserve a mention.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum about:

> ... but then why do C# users use using statements?

Simple: because they only have `using`, and not Java import. It is a build in property of that language, similar to the fact that C# supports the .Net platform, and Java (mainly) supports the JVM platform.

In other words: different languages follow different paradigms and concepts, very much like "real" human languages. Thus, in essence, the question `why does language A support feature X, but language B has Y` are (often, not always) not leading to much else but "because that is what the individual people wanted to have".